# Redshift - SQL - Cumulative average for grouped results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I currently have a table like so:

| Date | customer_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1/1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1/1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1/1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1/2 | 2 | 3 |
| 1/2 | 2 | 1 |
| 1/2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1/2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1/3 | 1 | 2 |
| 1/3 | 2 | 2 |
| 1/3 | 2 | 3 |
| 1/3 | 2 | 3 |

This eventually gets aggregated by the customer_id to get total_sales like so:

| customer_id | total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 13 |

I then calculate one metric based off of this table, average_sales, which is defined as:

`sum(total_sales) / count(distinct customer_id)`

This would result in average_sales of 10.5 based on the information above.

**However, I need to find a way to calculate this average but for each day on a cumulative basis like so:**

- Date 1/1 would be `sum(total sales) for 1/1 / count(distinct customer_ids) for 1/1`
- Date 1/2 would be `sum(total sales) for 1/1-1/2 / count(distinct customer_ids) for 1/1-1/2`
- Date 1/3 would be `sum(total sales) for 1/1-1/3 / count(distinct customer_ids) for 1/1-1/3`

The final day(1/3) should be equal to the overall average metric of 10.5.

Final table should look like this:

| Date | average_sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1 | 2 (4/2) |
| 1/2 | 5.5 (11/2) |
| 1/3 | 10.5 (21/2) |

I've tried multiple things thus far with grouping/window functions but can't seem to get the right numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the count of distinct customers the same for every month?  For example, if you removed customer 2 from `1/1`, should the average for `1/1` still divide by 2, or just by 1?  Similarly, if customer 3 appeared on `1/4`, should the preceding dates be divided by 2 or 3?

Comment: It would be count distinct for each time window. So if a new customer appeared on 1/4, then only day 4 (1/4) would be divided by 3. The previous days would remain divided by 2 because the new customer entered the window only on day 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you can't use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` with a window.

But, there's a hacky way to calculate it anyway.

1. Work out the first month each customer id appears
2. Rank the customers in order of when they appeared
3. `MAX(customer_rank)` is then the number of customers seen to date

This gives...

```
WITH
  check_first_date AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MIN(date_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id)   AS cust_id_first_date
  FROM
    example
),
  rank_customers_by_time AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cust_id_first_date, cust_id)  AS cust_rank
  FROM
    check_first_date
)
SELECT
  date_id,
  MAX(MAX(cust_rank)) OVER (ORDER BY date_id)   AS customers_to_date,
  SUM(SUM(sales))     OVER (ORDER BY date_id)   AS sales_to_date
FROM
  rank_customers_by_time
GROUP BY
  date_id
ORDER BY
  date_id
```

Then you can divide one by the other.

There are other ways to do the count-distinct over time, such as using correlated sub-queries.  I suspect (I haven't tested) that it's even slower though.

```
SELECT
  date_id,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lookup.cust_id)
      FROM example AS lookup
     WHERE lookup.date_id <= example.date_id
  )
    AS customers_to_date,
  SUM(SUM(sales))     OVER (ORDER BY date_id)   AS sales_to_date
FROM
  example
GROUP BY
  date_id
ORDER BY
  date_id
```

Here is a demo (using postgresql, as the clostest approximation to redshift) with slightly different data to show that it works even when customer id's appear 'out of order'.

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a5a37f3337e42123424c5cf1dbfe0152

***EDIT:*** An even shorter (faster?) version with windows

For each customer_id, identify which is their first ***row*** *(implicitly requires the rows to have a unique id)*.

The sum up the number of first rows that have occurred to date...

```
WITH
  check_first_occurrence AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id)   AS cust_id_first_id
  FROM
    example
)
SELECT
  date_id,
  SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN id = cust_id_first_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) OVER (ORDER BY date_id)   AS customers_to_date,
  SUM(SUM(sales                                            )) OVER (ORDER BY date_id)   AS sales_to_date
FROM
  check_first_occurrence
GROUP BY
  date_id
ORDER BY
  date_id
```

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=94e5fb624a89170aaf819e2b3ccd01d6

This version should be ***significantly*** more friendly to RedShift's horizontal scaling.

- Assuming, for example, you distribute by customer and sort by date